# http.get request loop closure issue (Node)

Tags: node.js, loops, get, request, closures

I want to be able to put in a range of URL in the commandline, and get the results of the requests for those in the order they were provided. I have looked into closures to achieve this as the callbacks will not be executed in order (more likely in which ever one responds the fastest)

```
for (var i = 2; i < process.argv.length; i++) {
  (function(index) {
    http.get(process.argv[index], function (response) {
      response.pipe(bl(function (err, data) {
        console.log(data.toString());
      }));
    });
  })(i);
}
```

The for loop over the arguments. Then each iteration calls the IIFE anonymous function which in turn calls the get request and so forth.
But the problem still remains, it is executed out of order. Not in the order the user requested.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just trying to log the results in order, but you want to the requests to run in parallel, then the usual solution to that is to collect the results in an array and then output the results when all the requests are done.

```
var count = process.argv.length - 2;
var results = new Array(count);
for (var i = 2; i < process.argv.length; i++) {
  (function(index) {
    http.get(process.argv[index], function (response) {
      response.pipe(bl(function (err, data) {
        results[index - 2] = data.toString();
        --count;
        if (count === 0) {
            for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
                console.log(results[j]);
            }
        }
      }));
    });
  })(i);
}
```

This brute force approach could also be made slightly smarter to output results a little bit sooner when all requests before this one are done rather than waiting for all to complete.

Another approach would be to use promises for each request and then use `Promise.all()` to wait for all the async operations to be done and `Promise.all()` will also collect all the results for you.

And, nodejs libraries like Async also have lots of functionality for managing a multitude of async operations.

---

It's actually a little simpler if you want to serialize the requests (only launch the next request when the prior one has finished).  That can be done like this:

```
function runAll() {
    var index = 2;
    function next() {
        if (index < process.argv.length) {
            http.get(process.argv[index], function (response) {
                response.pipe(bl(function (err, data) {
                    console.log(data.toString());
                    ++index;
                    next();
                }));
            });
        }
    }
    next();
}
```

---

And, here's a version using promises that runs the requests in parallel, but returns the results in order:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');

function runAll() {
    var promises = [];
    for (var i = 2; i < process.argv.length; i++) {
        promises.push(new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            http.get(process.argv[index], function (response) {
                response.pipe(bl(function (err, data) {
                    resolve(data.toString());
                }));
            });
        }));
    }
    return Promise.all(promises);
}

runAll().then(function(resultArray) {
    // resultArray contains an array of the results from all the operations, in order
    for (var i = 0; i < resultArray.length; i++) {
        console.log(resultArray[i]);
    }
});
```

Comment: That version is very simple. That's very readable. 
Your array solution is also really interesting. I didn't know that is was not possible to do it  with a closure  but without  the use of an array.

Comment: Is there a way to control callbacks in general?  I mean without the use of third party modules. I thought closures were the answer.  Using a closure doesn't seem to help me in this case, and I know I am doing it wrong.

Comment: @yahimeh - I coded two answers for you.  Promises are built into ES6 (or you can get a library to use them now) which would be another way.  Not sure what else you want.  A closure is used in both my solutions - you just weren't using one the right wey.

Comment: @yahimeh - I added a third version that uses promises which is how I'd generally approach a problem like this.